# Linear Regression of Two Non-Stationary Series

Tags: regression, time-series, stationarity, cointegration

I am working with two time series that are non-stationary. I would like to regress one to another (Y = Global Temperature Anomalies, X = C02 emissions) to see the relationship. However, I was wondering that the fact they are not stationary may cause some problems in the results. More, I read that cointegration may take an important role in this topic but not sure how to use it.

Could anyone clarify?

Thank you.

Comment: Long story short, you may do any regression you like, however the residuals of the regression should be stationary. Otherwise you are risking spurious regression problem. If there is cointegration, it means non stationary components (of variables that enter into regression) cancel out each other and residuals end up being stationary.

Comment: Okay so basically, if the series are cointegrated I am sure that the residuals are stationary, while if not I will go check if the residuals are stationary in order to accept the relationship. Many thanks!

Comment: Pretty much yes. But it is very unlikely that you know that the series are cointegrated beforehand unless you know the exact processes behind. It means you better always check the stationarity of the residuals (unless of course the components that enter into the regression are stationary in the first place).